# use macro if condition in email notification

Tags: macros, kentico

I am using a macro for `if` condition to check if a field is null or not, in a form email notification. I tried this one:

```cs
{% if(City != string.Empty) { $$value:City$$ } #%}
```

It did not work, and I am not getting the city value in the email body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `{%City%}` instead of `$$value:City$$`
- If you're simply not going to render the value of the "City" field if it's empty, you might as well just replace the whole block of code with just `{%City%}`
- Assuming your code is just a simplified example of what you are trying to accomplish, it should look like this:

```cs
    {% if(City != string.Empty) { return City; } %}
```

Comment: Hi Kristian, Thanks for your suggestion.This code works for me. I am upvoting your answer.